# The view customer_reg.views.Set_Checkout_Attributes didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am making an app in which after registration of user he refer to a page where he can click on a link to fill the another of order details.
when I am clicking on that link following view is active

```
def Checkout_Attributes(request):

    check_form = Check_Attribute_Form()
    context={'check_form':check_form}
    return render_to_response('checkout.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and after submitting the form following view is active

```
def Set_Checkout_Attributes(request):

    #if request.user.is_authenticated():
        #return HttpResponseRedirect('/checkout/')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        check_form = Check_Attribute_Form(request.POST)
            if check_form.is_valid():
            customer_check=Customer_check_attributes(billing_add=check_form.cleaned_data['billing_add'],shipping_add=check_form['shipping_add'],payment_method=check_form['payment_method'],shipping_method=check_form['shipping_method'],reward_points=check_form['reward_points'])
            customer_check.save()
            return render_to_response('sucess.html')
    else:
        check_form=Check_Attribute_Form()
        return render_to_response('a.html',{'check_form':check_form} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In this view I am getting the error of **Set_Checkout_Attributes didn't return an HttpResponse object.**

And one more thing when I am submitting the blank form it doesn't show the validation error

the template is as

```
<form action="/checkout1/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if check_form.errors  %}<h2>Please correct the following fields:</h2>{% endif %}
<div class="register_div">
        {% if check_form.billing_add.errors %}<p class="error">{{ check_form.billing_add.errors }}</p>{% endif %}
    <p><label for="billing_add" {% if check_form.billing_add.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}>Billing Address:</label></p>
    <p>{{ check_form.billing_add }}</p>
</div>
.
.
.
.
.
<p><input type="submit" value="submit" aly="register"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Is your code in `if check_form.is_valid():` indented properly.

Comment: yes it is !!!! here I am using multiple model concept and **Check_Attribute_Form** is the form of 2nd model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please use proper PEP-8 names for your variable and views.

Secondly, do not render a template on success - redirect to a new page.

Finally, think about the logic of your view. What happens when the form is not valid? What is returned in that circumstance? Look again at the example in the documentation, it shows exactly what structure you should use.